# Find the number of the ways of dividing $2p$ items into $2$ equal groups of $p$ each. Where the groups do not have distinct identity?

Tags: permutations, combinations

> Find the number of the ways of dividing $2p$ items into $2$ equal groups of $p$ each, where the groups do not have distinct identity?

Why is the solution to the above problem consisting of $\;\dfrac{(2p)!}{2!p!}$

Comment: Could you please make the question self-contained? And what do you mean by identity here?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think he means that the two groups are indistinguishable, i.e., putting things into two boxes, not box #1 and box #2

Comment: At this time, the wrong formula is being given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to rephrase your question: "How many ways can you divide $2p$ items into two groups of size $p$?"

This is close to "How many ways can you choose $p$ items from $2p$ items?" which is $\binom{2p}{p}= \frac{(2p)!}{p!p!}$. The $p$ unchosen items forms the other group.
However, if we do it this way, we count each pair of groups exactly twice, since we distinguish between the "chosen" group and the "unchosen" group. Since you do not distinguish between groups, just divide by $2$.

Note that the expression in your question is incorrect; maybe a typo?

---

Let's try a different version of the problem. How many ways can you divide $3p$ items into $3$ groups of size $p$?

Let's choose $p$ items to form the first group: $\binom{3p}{p}$.

Then, let's choose $p$ items from the remaining $2p$ items to form the second group: $\binom{2p}{p}$.

We'll let the remaining $p$ items be the third group.

Again, we've counted all *ordered triples* of groups (since we distinguish between "first," "second," and "third" groups), but we only want *unordered triples*. How many times did we overcount? The number of ways we can order 3 objects: $3!$.

So, our answer is $\binom{3p}{p} \binom{2p}{p} \frac{1}{3!}$.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Sorry,
it was a typo indeed.
the solution is (2p)!/2!(p!)^2, but am still unsure of the 2! which is one of the denominators. And why is it coming, since we are dealing only with Combinations not PERMUTATIONS?

Comment: @user88454 see my edit for an explanation of where $2!$ comes from

Answer (score 1):

Think about it like this.

- How many ways are there to form the (first) group of $p$, this is $2p$ choose $p$, so $(2p)!/(p!)^2$.
- Having selected a first group, the second one is fixed automatically. 
  So there are $(2p)!/(p!)^2$ ways to form a first group and a second group.
- But, you do not have a first group and a second group. So, this is not yet the good number. Each forming of groups appears twice, so you need to divide by $2=2!$ for a result of  $(2p)!/(2!(p!)^2)$ which is not quite what your wrote.

If  this is not an error in you typing the problem, please provide more details, since there might be a different interpretation.